# Revoke refresh_token on change password

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

We have one web application that is built on Asp.Net and then we have IdentityServer4 application built with .net core.

We have mobile application which serves as client to IdentityServer4 for login and it's grants are stored in SQL database.

Problem I have is when as an admin I change/reset password from web application, mobile application is still accessible because refresh_token is still valid as we have set sliding expiration for that. What I want is to revoke refresh_token when admin resets the password for any user, I don't find way to do it in asp.net application, I have used below document, but that is not useful to me as I believe this will be helpful only if we want to revoke grants for logged in user.

https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/revocation.html

PS: We do have revoke functionality in identityServer project, but that is different project, we want similar revoke in asp.net web application.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you store the tokens? You can check this link to revoke a token [link](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/revocation.html)

Comment: I have used same link, but that is not useful to me, And I am storing tokens in SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

How about this method? this is called on the event of of SigningOut. You signout the user on password change and revoke the token.

```
.AddCookie("cookie", options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "mvccode";

        options.Events.OnSigningOut = async e =>
        {
            // revoke refresh token on sign-out
            await e.HttpContext.RevokeUserRefreshTokenAsync();
        };
    })
```

Link to the documentation - [here](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetcore/web.html).

Comment: I am changing password from admin user, so I want to revoke grant so that user for which admin has change the password has to again login and use the new tokens.

Comment: Is your application a SPA? Are you changing the password via IdentityServer endpoint or have written your custom code in a controller to do so?